# How to make a textbox and button show in anchorTag click of html

Tags: html, anchor

On load of html,it should have a anchor tag.on clicking that anchor tag.show one text box and button.enter some value in textbox and clicking the button should append the value entered to the anchor tag (anchor tag + value)

Comment: have you tried anything so far ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML:
Put both `textbox` and `button` to `display:none`

```
<a href="#" id="anchr" >Click here</a>
<input type="text" value="" id="txt" style="display:none;"/>
<input type="button" value="Button" id="btn" style="display:none;"/>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#anchr').click(function(){  
$('#txt').show(); // show textbox
$('#btn').show(); //show button
});
$('#btn').click(function(){
$('#anchr').html($('#anchr').html() + $('#txt').val()); // Anchor tag HTML + Value of Textbox
});
});
```

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wphz8u5v/1/)